# 2007 Ford Focus wagon

Tags: ford, starting, focus

While driving home the car coughed a couple of times then stopped. We tried to start it and it wont start not even click all the lights still work and the dash still lights up the radio even still plays but it will not turn over.

If the starter is bad can it cause the car to die while driving?

Comment: Do you have any codes?

Comment: Can you measure if the battery voltage is good? If the alternator died the battery might still have enough juice to run the radio and lights weakly, but not the fuel pump or starter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of guessing, you should first do a continuity test with a Probe Light Tester.

Check out this video to learn more about using a Probe Light Tester.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjCjmwUxUSU

If you are not sure about your skills then just go to your local auto parts store and ask if they will scan your vehicle for you.  this will get you the error code for what's wrong with your vehicle and it may also tell you the direct malfunction as well as the suggested remedy for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine says the starter motor is not the fault, when the car has started it won't just stop via the starter motor, even to the point where it can physically be removed.
He says it maybe the ecu main feed.